# jq: output array of json objects

Tags: bash, jq

Say I have the input:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@company.com"
}
{
    "name": "Brad",
    "email": "brad@company.com"
}
```

How do I get the output:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@company.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Brad",
        "email": "brad@company.com"
    }
]
```

I tried both:

```
jq '[. | {name, email}]'
```

and

```
jq '. | [{name, email}]'
```

which both gave me the output

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@company.com"
    }
]
[
    {
        "name": "Brad",
        "email": "brad@company.com"
    }
]
```

I also saw no options for an array output in the documentations, any help appreciated

Comment: How do I give a name to the new array instead of it being an anonymous array?  So { "people": [ {  "name": "Brad", "email": "brad@company.com" } ]}

Comment: @user372429 you would just wrap the {people: } around your output, so it should look something like: jq -s '{people: . }' < tmp.json

Comment: try jq

`[.[] | {name,email}]`

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Use slurp mode:

> ```
>   o   --slurp/-s:
>
>       Instead of running the filter for each JSON object
>       in the input, read the entire input stream into a large
>       array and run the filter just once.
> ```

```
$ jq -s '.' < tmp.json
[
  {
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@company.com"
  },
  {
    "name": "Brad",
    "email": "brad@company.com"
  }
]
```

Comment: You can also pipe initial jq results into `jq -s` if you need to. I.E
`... | jq '.foo[].bar' | jq -s`

Comment: I like adding another pipe to reduce steps in each command, but don't forget the '.' `... | jq '.foo[].bar' | jq -s '.'`

Comment: @Adam `jq` assumes a filter of `.` if its standard output is a terminal.

Comment: You can just wrap the filter in `[...]` instead of running `jq` a second time; `... | jq '[.foo[].bar]'`.

Comment: @chepner, I was piping into further commands, so the default didn't kick in for me. Sorry, I'd thought you had missed that last part.

Comment: some shells are giving issue with using ... | jq -s. Faced issue with redirecting output to a file as ... |  jq -s > file.json, So make sure you use ... |  jq -s '.' > file.json

Comment: @tarvinder91 That's not the shell; that's `jq` detecting that its standard output isn't a terminal device, and so requiring an explicit filter.

Comment: @chepner 's answer should be the accepted answer!

Comment: "You can just wrap the filter in `[...]` instead of running `jq` a second time; `... | jq '[.foo[].bar]'`"

If I use `jq '[.]'` with the OP's file as input, I receive the OP's undesired output. How does wrapping the filter produce the desired output?