# json array into json stream with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

This task is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38061346/jq-output-array-of-json-objects) but in my case I would like to go other way around.
So say we have input:

```
[
    {
        "name": "John",
        "email": "john@company.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Brad",
        "email": "brad@company.com"
    }
]
```

and desired output is:

```
{
    "name": "John",
    "email": "john@company.com"
}
{
    "name": "Brad",
    "email": "brad@company.com"
}
```

I tried to write a bash function which will do it in loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

json=`cat $1`
length=`echo $json | jq '. | length'`

for (( i=0; i<$length ; i++ ))
do
echo $json | jq ".[$i]"
done
```

but it is obviously extremly slow...

Is there any way how to use `jq` better for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
jq '.[]' file
```

If you use the `.[index]` syntax, but omit the index entirely, it will return all of the elements of an array.

**Test:**

```
$ jq '.[]' file
{
  "email": "john@company.com",
  "name": "John"
}
{
  "email": "brad@company.com",
  "name": "Brad"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can apply  ".[]" filter.

This tutorial is very informative
https://stedolan.github.io/jq/tutorial/