# Sending concatenated files to JQ with wrapped as JSON array

Tags: json, jq

I have a curious problem sending concatenated files to [JQ](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/). I'm using Windows 10, but the problem is surfacing with Bash (via Git Bash) as well.

I have several input JSON files in the form `input-1.json`, `input-2.json`, `input-3.json`, etc. The contents of each is a nested object that looks like this:

```json
{
  "blah": "blah",
  "foo": [{
      "bar" {…}
    }, {
      "bar" {…}
    }]
}
```

I want to concatenate the files and extract all the values of "bar" across all the files into one array. (Note that "foo" is an array of objects, each with "bar" containing its own object.) In other words, I want to end up with (placed on one line for readability here):

```json
[{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Note that these are the foo…bars *across all the files*!

I start with this:

```
type input-*.json | jq ".foo[].bar" > output.json
```

That gives me

```
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}
```

Close! Now I just have to wrap them in `[…]`, right? So I do this:

```
type input-*.json | jq "[.foo[].bar]" > output.json
```

Uh, oh; it gives me the following:

```
[{…}, {…}, {…}], [{…}, {…}]
```

But why? At the point of `.foo[].bar`, JQ just sees a stream of objects, right? How does JQ "remember" that some of those objects came from different inputs?

Note that [How to convert a JSON object stream into an array with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29404575) and [jq: output array of json objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38061346) seem to be similar questions. They say to use JQ's `--slurp` mode. But won't that prevent streaming, i.e. if the output of all the files is really huge, won't it this have the potential of running out of memory by loading the entire input into memory?

Besides (and this is the crux of my confusion), if `jq ".foo[].bar"` gives me exactly the `{…}, {…}, {…}], [{…}, {…}` array contents I want, how does JQ "remember" that some of those objects came from different inputs? You'll see that JQ isn't wrapping each `{…}` in an array, but actually wrapping several objects based upon which `input-*.json` file it came from. Why?

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to "slurp" the files, like so:

```
jq -s 'map( .foo[].bar )' input-*.json
```

If you want to save memory, you could go with:

```
jq -n '[inputs | .foo[].bar]' input-*.json
```

If your shell does not support filename globbing, then you would have to specify the file names in some other way, e.g. as in the Q.

Comment: But can you explain _why_? If the output of `.foo[].bar` is merely a stream of JSON objects, how does JQ "remember" that some of them come from one input file and some of them come from another? And how are you using `input-*.json`—does JQ support wildcards? And what is `map(…)`, and why is it needed?

Comment: Please read the description of the -s option in the jq manual.  jq itself does not support wildcards in file name specifications; in a Windows environment, you might have to specify the files in some other way, e.g. as in the Q.